# Scripting After Effects

Tags: scripting, expression, after-effects

I need to learn Affect Effect expressions and scripting fast.

Can you recommend any resources on this topic?

I've got a pretty knowledge of other scripting concept and languages like javascript. I just need the know-how on after effect scripting itself..

I'm using AE9

Thanks a mill!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the standard (if not *the* standard) intro-to-AE-scripting sites, courtesy of Dan Ebberts: http://www.motionscript.com/

Sign up for the AE mailing list as well.  It's a great resource for asking anything AE related. http://www.media-motion.tv/ae-list.html

Comment: This is quite an old question, I've worked my way through it using some random sample. 
Thanks for trying to answer it though!